# After moving the wordpress site to different server admin section is blank

Tags: wordpress

I recently moved one wordpress site to a different server.
After moving to different server the frontend works well but the admin section is blank.

If I **rename the plugins directory** the admin section also works.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you find which plugin is causing problem, Check your plugin main php file (ex. - myplugin.php) and check whether php tag opening and closing is proper or not`(<?php ,?>)`.

Some times because of that it can cause problem because may be your code outputting something before header sent ("**Header already sent error**") and you will get "White screen of death" so try by simply removing closing tag (?>) from end of file or check properly for tag. I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a plugin that is triggered on admin page, that has an error. Try renaming the plugin's folder one by one and find out which plugin is causing the error.

You also might want  to check your apache error log. I'm sure you'll find an answer there.

Fun Fact - That blank page is actually called a White screen of death in WordPress terminology.

Read more here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#The_White_Screen_of_Death